# Set current display title from the $views object

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I'm doing some work in hook_views_query_alter() and from there I have access to the $views and $query objects by reference.

I am altering the query, but there's a bit of logic that I'd like to keep in the same place to  modify the title of this display (it's a block).

My display object is this: `$view->display[$view->current_display]`

I just can't seem to figure out how to change the display title from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to change it from build_info.

```
$view->build_info['title'] = "New title";
```

Comment: Hah, I was convinced it was in the display property, didn't even think to look for it below.  Thank you very much, works great!